# Converting numeric values in OBJC to values of time? (hours instead of percent of an hour)

Tags: objective-c, double, nsmutablestring

I'm currently trying to convert xml values that represents two times.

example:

```
<from>960</from>
<to>975</to>
```

i store these 2 values into two doubles:

```
double From = from;
double To = to;
```

Now, if i do

```
From=From/60;
To=To/60;
```

and

```
NSString *fromString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",From];
NSString *toString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",To];
```

i thereafter smash these together to one string separated by " - " and `NSLog` the new string:

```
NSLog(@"New String: %@",FromToString);
```

The output: 16:00-16:25

Now, what i'm trying to accomplish here is for the `FromToString` to get the value 16:00 - 16:15

So, the question is how do i recalculate this to represent hours in 60minutes instead of percent of an hour? O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all you want is to have a double (eg. 9.5) converted to a string (in this case: 09:30), right?

You can do it like that:

```
// get hours
NSInteger hours = (int)floor(number);

// get minutes
NSInteger minutes = (int)floor((number-hours)*60);

// construct string
NSString* timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02d:%02d", hours, minutes];
```

cheers (not tested though)

Answer (score 1):

you will need two variables, something like

```
fromHours = floor(from/60);
fromMinues = from % 60;
NSString fromTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%02f:%02f", 
                                               fromHours, fromMinues);
```

and the same for the other variable.

Comment: This worked, thanks. However jaydee3's answer also worked and he was a tad faster. And i can only accept one answer, but i'll +1 you! Thanks!